# How to split a Pytorch tensor into different dimensions?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I’m new to Pytorch .

Let’s say I have a tensor that has this shape `torch.size([1, 25200, 11])`

I want to split it into 3 smaller tensors , each of 3 smaller tensors has the shape of 1st.
`torch.size([1, 3, 80, 80, 11])` and 2nd `torch.size([1, 3, 40, 40 , 11])`
and `3rd torch.size([1, 3, 20, 20, 11)].`

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Explain those numbers:

80x80x3 = 19200

40x40x3 = 4800

20x20x3=1200 , add these result we have 25200, 1 is batch size, 11 is classes + xywh

Comment: As you would similarly do with `numpy` you can use the `torch.Tensor` methods to modify a given tensor ( https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html ). For example you can index into your tensor `x` by `y = x[:, 0:19200, :]` then reshape `y = y.reshape([1, 3, 80, 80, 11])`.

Comment: Thanks, your comment is similar to @andrew Holmgren , lets me test with my original tensor I'll let you know if it works in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
import torch
tensor = torch.ones((1, 25200, 11))
first_break = tensor[:, 0:19200, :].view((1, 3, 80, 80, 11))
second_break = tensor[:, 19200:19200+4800, :].view((1, 3, 40, 40, 11))
third_break = tensor[:, 19200+4800:19200+4800+1200, :].view((1, 3, 20, 20, 11))
```

If you give a bit more explanation and context the code could get cleaned up and not be so hardcoded, or maybe this gives you enough to run with.

Comment: Thank for the answer .Actually I'm playing with Scaled YOLOv4 , I converted Scaled YOLOV4 model to ONNX format, when I inference with onnx model, it gives me a tensor with shape of torch.size([1, 25200, 11)] . When I convert the .pt to .onnx the export_pt2onnx.py concat 3 yolo layers that has above shape to (1 , 25200, 11) so I want to split ([1, 25200, 11)] back to 3 original tensors (3 yolo layers)  so I can do inference on it.

Comment: @frankenstein No problem, figured that something like that was going on. Yeah, pretty easy to use that code block for a single inference. I haven't played with onnx much, but if you are running a batch inference you probably will need to break the 25200*n into chunks of 25200. view(n,.) instead of view(1,..) should work but not super sure how onnx will structure it, might need some dimension permutation or something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```py
  T1= torch.narrow(YourTensor, 1,0 , 80*80*3)
  T1v = T1.view(1,3,80,80,11)

  T2= torch.narrow(YourTensor, 1,80*80*3 , 40*40*3)
  T2v = T2.view(1,3,40,40,11)

  T3= torch.narrow(YourTensor, 1,80*80*3 + 40*40*3 , 20*20*3)
  T3v = T3.view(1,3,20,20,11)
```